# Calculating self citation counts in DBLP using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have imported the DBLP database with referenced publications from Crossref API into neo4j.

The goal is to calculate a self-citation-quotient for each author in the database.
The way I´d like to calculate this quotient is the following:

1. find authors that have written publications referencing another publication written by the same author
2. for each of these publications count the referenced publications written by the same author
3. divide amount of self references by the amount of all references
4. set this number as a parameter `scq`(self citation quotient) for the publication
5. sum all values of `scq` and divide them by the total amount of publications written by the author
6. set this value as a property `scq` for the Author

As an example I have the following sub-graph for the author "Danielle S. Bassett":

[image]

From the graph you can see that she has 2 publications that contain self-references.
In Words:
Danielle wrote Publication 1, 2, 3, 4
Publication 1 references publication 2
Publication 3 references publication 4

My attempt was to use the following cypher query:

```
match (a:Author{name:"Danielle S. Bassett"})-[:WROTE]->(p1:Publication)-[r:REFERENCES]->(p2:Publication)<-[:WROTE]-(a)
with count(p2) as ssc_per_publ,
     count(p1) as main_publ_count,
     collect(p2) as self_citations,
     collect(p1) as main_publ,
     collect(r) as refs,
     a as author
return author, main_publ, ssc_per_publ, self_citations, main_publ_count, refs
```

The result of this query as a table looks like this:

[image]

As you can see from the table the `main_publ_count` is calculated correctly since there are 2 publications she has written that contain self references but the `ssc_per_publ` (self citation count per publication) is wrong because it counted ALL self references. But I need the count of self references for EACH PUBLICATION.

Calculating the quotients will not be the problem but getting the right values from neo4j is.

I hope I´ve expressed myself clearly enough for you to understand the issue.
Maybe someone of you knows a way of getting this right. Thanks!

Comment: What should be the value of `ssc_per_publ`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `WITH` clause is using `author` as the sole [aggregation function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/#query-functions-aggregating) "grouping key", since it is the only term in that clause not using an aggregation function. So, all the aggregation functions in that clause are aggregating over just that one term.

To get a "self citation count" per publication (by that author), you'd have to do something like the following (for simplicity, this query ignores all the other counts and collections). `author` and `publ` together form the "grouping key" in this query.

```
MATCH (author:Author{name:"Danielle S. Bassett"})-[:WROTE]->
  (publ:Publication)-[r:REFERENCES]->(p2:Publication)<-[:WROTE]-(a)
RETURN author, publ, COUNT(p2) as self_citation_count;
```

*[Aside: your original query has other issues as well. For example, you should use `COUNT(DISTINCT p1) as main_publ_count` so that multiple self-citations to the same `p1` instance will not inflate the count of "main" publications.]*

Comment: Hey. Thanks yeah that works perfectly!
Now I would like to write this value for all authors into the main_publ.
So I just do something like:
match (a:Author)-[:WROTE]->(p1:Publication)-[r:REFERENCES]->(p2:Publication)<-[:WROTE]-(a)
with a as author,
  p1 as main_publ,
     count(distinct p2) as self_citation_count
set main_publ.ssq = SIZE(self_citations)

All self_citation_counts are correct but not correctly written into the parameter?!
That doesn´t make any sense for me o.O

Comment: Something seems to be missing. `self_citations` is not defined in above query.